# How to fix Key error "Item" dynamodb, if item does not exist?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb

```
def func(name):
  ddb = session.resource(service_name="dynamodb")
    table = ddb.Table("TABLE_X")

    response = table.get_item(Key={"employee": user})
    data = response["Item"]

    for item in data.items():
        if data["employee"] == name:
            manager = data["manager"]
            return name, manager
        return False
```

ddb table has:

| employee | manager |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | John |
|  |  |
| Ben | Mike |

I want to be able to say, if user does not exist, return no user found.

I understand that it will return Key error if it doesn't exist, so how can I achieve that in a way that it will return me an output no user found instead of the key error?

Comment: Why can't you check with `if 'Item' in response`?

Comment: But then, what do you mean by 'output'? the code snipped is obviously from a function (as it returns something). so what should the function return in the error case. So far it is a tuple. One way to do this would be an Exception, but then you need to reflect that in the caller. So, please provide more details and all the relevant code.

Comment: So right now it throws a Key Error "Item" if the user does not exist, instead of Key Error, id prefer it to say no user found output. The piece of code above gives mt the user and manager when they exist

Comment: From context, `data` appears to be a python dictionary.  If this code throws a key error, it's because "employee" is not a key in `data`.  I see that your code makes no use of the index variable `item`, which almost has to be an error.  It makes no sense to iterate over something and not look at the items themselves.

Comment: Made correction, I am aware of the key names so i didnt need to check those. If I add else print("not found") thats where the key error comes in. Because say the value of name="Sam"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if a key is in a dictionary with `'foo' in bar`. So judging from the comments you want to return `False` and print an error message if something is not found.

---

**explicit check**

For each key you want, check if it exists:

```
def func(name):
    ddb = session.resource(service_name="dynamodb")
    table = ddb.Table("TABLE_X")

    response = table.get_item(Key={"employee": user})
    if not 'Item' in response:
        print('User not found')
        return False 

    data = response["Item"]

    for item in data.items():
        if "employee" in data and data["employee"] == name:
            manager = data["manager"]
            return name, manager
        return False
```

---

**Implicit check (catch the error)***

The method above has a high likelyhood of missing an occetion to check ... There is a python build in way to deal with expected errors...

```
def func(name):
    try:
        ddb = session.resource(service_name="dynamodb")
        table = ddb.Table("TABLE_X")

        response = table.get_item(Key={"employee": user})
        data = response["Item"]

        for item in data.items():
            if data["employee"] == name:
                manager = data["manager"]
                return name, manager
            return False
    except KeyError as e:
        print('User could not be found. Original error:', e.message)
        return False
```